# CMD Double command on 1 line does not work in windows 10

Tags: cmd

I have the command:

```
start cmd /k cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Mirtt & php artisan serve
```

in a .bat file.

Reading around on google tels me that & wil make that both commands are executed however only the dirst cd command is executed the second one is ignored.

I think it has to do with windows 10, since all examples I read on the internet are on windows 7/8

Thanks in advance

Comment: `start cmd /k cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Mirtt ^& php artisan serve`

Comment: Thank you, I saw the ^command no where.

Answer (score 0):

Since folder name has spaces you have to put it under quotes, like this:

```
start cmd /k cd "C:\xampp\htdocs\Mirtt & php artisan serve"
```

Comment: It already worked with adding ^ in front of the &.. But thanks anyways!